# How can I add a unique auto increment ID inside mongoDB object

Tags: mongodb

I have a table users. This is the schema.

```
var usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  uname : {type : String , unique: true},
  email : {type : String},
  logintype : {type : String},
  password : String,
  status : String,
  hash : String,
  social: {},
  games: Object,
  os: String,
  friends: Object,
  msges:Object
});
```

The msges are objects. But what I want is to have key value pair inside msges. So what I did was

```
function sendMsgToFriend(uname,friendUname,title,msg,time,callback){
  global.users.find({"uname":friendUname},
    function(err,doc){
        if(err){
          callback(false,err,"Msg cannot be sent");
        }else{
          global.users.update( {"uname" : uname},
            {
              $addToSet : {
                "msges":{time:{"from":uname,"title":title,"msg":msg,"read":false}}
              }
            },function(err,doc){
              if(err){
                  callback(false,err,"Msg cannot be sent");
              }else{
                  callback(true,null,"Msg has been sent");
              }
            }
          );
        }
    }
  );
}
```

I tried to make 'time' the key and rest its value. But what happened was that instead of value of time, string "time" appeared. Can I make an auto increment Key of msges? Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define "msgs" as a object but what i read from your question is you want a array of objects..

Why don't you create a model for messages and make make "msgs" an array of references to that object.

```
var usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  uname : {type : String , unique: true},
  email : {type : String},
  logintype : {type : String},
  password : String,
  status : String,
  hash : String,
  social: {},
  games: Object,
  os: String,
  friends: Object,
  msges: [{
      message_id : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' },
      read_on : Boolean }]
});
```

and a schema for the messages

```
var messageSchema = Schema({
  from : String,
  title: String,
  msg : String,
  send_on : Date
});

var Message  = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
```

This way all messages are in a collection and you can track the read status per user.

For retrieving the messages during user retriaval you can use [mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

UPDATE:
if you don't want an xtra collection make your user schema something like:

```
var usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      uname : {type : String , unique: true},
      email : {type : String},
      logintype : {type : String},
      password : String,
      status : String,
      hash : String,
      social: {},
      games: Object,
      os: String,
      friends: Object,
      msges: [{
          id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          from : String,
          title: String,
          msg : String,
          send_on : Date,
          read_on : Boolean }]
    });
```

But keep in mind that if you also want the message to be present with the user who sended it you need to put it in the array by both users (keep id equal).... So you should think / talk about the best solution in your scenario.

Comment: I thought of it as well but they don't want another table. They want it to be nested inside it.

Comment: You can also include the schema in the User table so you don't get another collection

Comment: can you be a more brief? this is my first project :(

Comment: I used this. msges: [{id : ObjectId,data : Object}] but it says that ObjectId is not defined.

Comment: changed my answer the mongoose type is : Schema.Types.ObjectId

Comment: Bit I don't want the message table. It should be blank. Isn't it possible?

Comment: When you don't specify a message schema you don't get a messages colleciton.
The id in the msges array you can use to unique identify the message (when you want it also in the sendbox of the sending user for example...) When that's not a requirement you could ignore the id field...

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks for your time. :)